Deprecation Warning and Missing Cache File Issue in tsx Generate Script
I'm running a script using tsx with the command npm run generate, and encountering the following output:

Using 'openai' model provider   Generating storage context...
(node:23984) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The punycode module is
deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.   (Use node --trace-deprecation ... to show where the warning was created)   No valid data found at path: .cache\index_store.json starting new store.
Warning: TT: undefined function: 32   Storage context successfully
generated in 0.791s.   Finished generating storage.

Issues:
Deprecation Warning:
    The punycode module is deprecated, but I'm unsure which dependency is using it or how to resolve the warning.

Missing Cache File:
    The script mentions "No valid data found at path: .cache\index_store.json starting new store." How should I handle this? Should I create this file manually, or is it expected to be generated by the script?

Undefined Function:
    The warning "TT: undefined function: 32" appears during the script execution, but it's unclear what TT refers to or which part of my script is causing this.

Context:

I'm using Node.js version v22.12.0.
The script being run is located at app/api/chat/engine/generate.ts.
I've already tried running npm install and updating dependencies, but the issue persists.

How can I resolve these warnings and ensure the script runs without errors?
